# Sorting archive pages with "pretty" URLs?

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination, archives, sort

We want the users to re-order the posts on a page similar to pagination but I can't find anything anywhere!

It would be great to create a link to a url similar to `.../page/2/title/`, `title` being the new order. Is this even possible?!

Found several pagination scripts but none offer this option...

Comment: Try appending the URL of the page with the order and/or order by you want, eg. `example.com/somepage/page/2/?order=desc&orderby=title` ..both the `order` and `orderby` parameters are public query variables(ie. you can query by them directly in the URL).

Comment: ah cool! Think there's a way to make em safe URLs?

Comment: I'd suggest updating your question to reflect what you're asking regarding creating pretty URLs(since this is now the primary basis of your question). Additionally it may help to have a quick search for custom rewrite rule related topics to get an idea of what's involved with creating custom rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a rewrite rule with an order part is very easy, if you do it for one site. It would be harder if you want to create a generic solution that works for all installations with all kinds of permalink structures and custom taxonomies.

This short example works on a basic install of WordPress 3.1, with no extra custom taxonomies. I use the `orderby` prefix to prevent conflicts with existing post names:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse13483_init' );
function wpse13483_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( 'category/(.+?)/orderby/([^/]+)(/page/?([0-9]{1,}))?/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[4]&orderby=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'tag/([^/]+)/orderby/([^/]+)(/page/?([0-9]{1,}))?/?$', 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[4]&orderby=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'type/([^/]+)/orderby/([^/]+)(/page/?([0-9]{1,}))?/?$', 'index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[4]&orderby=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'author/([^/]+)/orderby/([^/]+)(/page/?([0-9]{1,}))?/?$', 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[4]&orderby=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/orderby/([^/]+)(/page/?([0-9]{1,}))?/?$', 'index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[6]&orderby=$matches[4]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/orderby/([^/]+)(/page/?([0-9]{1,}))?/?$', 'index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[5]&orderby=$matches[3]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '([0-9]{4})/orderby/([^/]+)(/page/?([0-9]{1,}))?/?$', 'index.php?year=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[4]&orderby=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}
```

Comment: hey jan - thanks for this! It seems to be the way forward but i can't seem to get it to work with the URL http://bfami.modernactivity.co.uk/category/educational-projects/page/2/orderby/title/. I know it should be the first rule but it doesn't catch?

Comment: @daniel: I forgot to recommend my [Rewrite analyzer plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608), which shows you the current rewrite rules and lets you experiment with URLs. Remember that you should flush your rules too, by visiting the *Permalinks* page.

Comment: ah - got the working after re-saving my permalink settings! Also managed to incorp order/asc or desc too so thanks very much.